# SHA256 Hash doesn't match the one listed on Bitcoin Wiki

Tags: encryption, bitcoin, sha256

I am trying to create a bitcoin address by following the steps shown [here](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Technical_background_of_version_1_Bitcoin_addresses). However, I am getting a different hash then the one shown in step 2.

Calculating the SHA256 hash on:

```
0250863ad64a87ae8a2fe83c1af1a8403cb53f53e486d8511dad8a04887e5b2352
```

Gives me the output:

```
a9ce83de3a0ff3516b7c50cdd787e9f69f152f227d93c9512774231e7132e925
```

The problem is according to the Bitcoin wiki I should get the following hash:

```
0b7c28c9b7290c98d7438e70b3d3f7c848fbd7d1dc194ff83f4f7cc9b1378e98
```

Can someone explain why I am not getting the same hash as the wiki?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are treating `0250863ad64a87ae8a2fe83c1af1a8403cb53f53e486d8511dad8a04887e5b2352` as an ascii string, whereas you should be treating it as a hex representation of 32 bytes.

If you use it as a string, you get:

```
echo -n "0250863ad64a87ae8a2fe83c1af1a8403cb53f53e486d8511dad8a04887e5b2352" | openssl sha256
(stdin)= a9ce83de3a0ff3516b7c50cdd787e9f69f152f227d93c9512774231e7132e925
```

If you treat it as bytes, you get the right result:

```
echo -n "0250863ad64a87ae8a2fe83c1af1a8403cb53f53e486d8511dad8a04887e5b2352" | xxd -p -r | openssl sha256
(stdin)= 0b7c28c9b7290c98d7438e70b3d3f7c848fbd7d1dc194ff83f4f7cc9b1378e98
```